# Issue with Proxy Pattern in c++

Tags: c++

I was told to use proxy pattern in my program which is not that clear to me.

I have some issues with `Proxy &operator*()` , I don't know what should I return there to get a value of current index in file.

I had this before and it worked:

```
int &operator*()
{
    return ptr->getValue(index);
}
```

But I was told to change it to `Proxy`.

If I compile with `Proxy &operator*()` then I'm getting

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'IntFile::Proxy&'
>   from expression of type 'int'|

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class IntFile
{
public:
    int value;
    FILE* file;

    IntFile()
    {
        file = fopen("text.txt", "r+b");
    }

    ~IntFile()
    {
        fclose(file);
    }

    virtual int& getValue(int index)
    {
        fseek(file, 4*index, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&value, 4, 1, file);
        return value;
    }

    virtual int setValue(int value)
    {
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_CUR);
        fwrite(&value, 4, sizeof(value),file);
        return 0;
    }

    class Proxy
    {
    private:
        IntFile *ptr;
        long index;
    public:
        Proxy(IntFile* ptr3)
        {
            ptr = ptr3;
        }
        Proxy& operator=(int value)
        {
            ptr->setValue(value);
        }
        operator int() const
        {
            return ptr->getValue(index);
        }
    };

    friend struct iterator;
    struct iterator
    {
        int index;
        int value2;
        IntFile* ptr;

        iterator(IntFile* ptr2, int idx, FILE* ptrfile)
        {
            ptr = ptr2;
            index = idx;
            fseek(ptrfile, 4*index, SEEK_SET);
        }

        bool operator==(const iterator&other) const
        {
            return index == other.index;
        }

        bool operator!=(const iterator&other) const
        {
            return index!=other.index;
        }

        Proxy &operator*()
        {
            // How to do that?
        }

        int &operator=(int value)
        {
            this->value2 = value;
        }

        iterator&operator++()
        {
            this->index = index+1;
        }

        iterator&operator--()
        {
            this->index = index -1;
        }
    };

    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator(this, 0, file);
    }

    iterator end(int number)
    {
        return iterator(this, number, file);
    }

    iterator rbegin(int number)
    {
        return iterator(this, number-1, file);
    }

    iterator rend()
    {
        return iterator(this, -1, file);
    }
};

int main()
{
    IntFile myfile;

    int number;
    cout << "Enter number of elements: " << endl;
    cin >> number;

    vector <int> myVector;

    cout << "Enter your numbers: ";
    for ( int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        cin >> myfile.value;
        myVector.push_back(myfile.value);
    }

    fwrite(&myVector[0], sizeof(vector<int>::value_type), myVector.size(),myfile.file);

    cout << endl << "FORWARD 1 by 1: " << endl;
    for (IntFile::iterator i = myfile.begin(); i != myfile.end(number); ++i)
    {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }

    cout << endl << "BACKWARD 1 by 1: " << endl;
    for (IntFile::iterator i = myfile.rbegin(number); i != myfile.rend(); --i)
    {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning a proxy requires of you to return a proxy **object**. You attempt to return a reference to such an object, but it doesn't exit. And we cannot bind a proxy reference to an integer.

The fix is simple, just return a new object by value:

```
Proxy operator*()
{
  return Proxy(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused, but I'm getting this error for now 
invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'IntFile::Proxy&' from a temporary of type 'IntFile::Proxy*'|

Comment: @MeghanCristen - You did not change the operators return type! Note how I wrote it.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but can you have a look at it one more time, it it's not a trouble for you? I have problems with output now, If I input 5 and 1,2,3,4,5 i should get 1 2 3 4 5 and 5 4 3 2 1 in return of iterator, but I'm getting 6 6 6 6 6 and 5 5 5 5 5

Comment: @MeghanCristen - You have an `index` member in your proxy. It's un-initialized. You need to initialize it as well, in the constructor of `Proxy`.

Comment: i'm not entering `operator int() const` in `Proxy` to get value, should this operator work when `Proxy(ptr)` is returned?

Comment: @MeghanCristen - How did you conclude you aren't entering there? Your program won't build this expression `cout << *i` if it wasn't entered. You need to fix the issue I mentioned before. Also, [I suggest you read this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: well I made a `cout << "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" << endl;` inside and I can't see it in console I made such suggestion. And thanks for the link, definetly going to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Proxy &operator*()
{
            // How to do that?
            return *this;
 }
```

It avoid you to create another new Proxy